# Display height changing iframe 100% on div

Tags: php, css, html, iframe, height

What i have:
I have a player status script for our Minecraft Server which displays the name of the server the ip and the heads of the current players. 2 Div boxes for the statusbox: An outer 1 to fix the position and the 2nd one for the divbox itself.

What i want:
I want the current divbox where the iframes are in:

```
<div class="statusbox">

<div class="statusboxinner">
<iframe src="players_main.php" height="auto" width="140px" frameborder="0"           scrolling="no" padding="fixed" marginheight="auto"></iframe> <iframe src="players_hg.php" height="auto" width="140px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="auto"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

To be 100% fixed to the php file which is loaded by the iframes.

CSS codes:

```
 .statusbox {
position: fixed;
background: none;
margin-top: 472px;
margin-left: 1000px;
#pointer-events:none;
z-index:0;
}


.statusboxinner {
float: right;
margin-right: -243px;
#pointer-events:auto;
position: relative;
padding: auto;
height:auto;
padding-top:auto;
margin-bottom:auto;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 3px;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px black;
box-shadow: inset -4px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

You can look at it on this page www.ravand.org (right floating box)

What my problem is:
I could simply add a fixed amount of pixels to be the height of the divbox but the problem is, that according to how many people are playing on the server the php file/ the iframe enlarges to the bottom.
When i try to set "height:100%" the statusbox simply just gets enlarged all the way to the buttom which is not what i need.

I would gladly solve this problem without iframes if you have any suggestions.

Thanks in advance
ravand

Answer (score 0):

found a cool script I think should do the trick [here](http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=26417).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--//
    function sizeFrame() {
        var F = document.getElementById("myFrame");
        if(F.contentDocument) {
            F.height = F.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight+30; //FF 3.0.11, Opera 9.63, and Chrome
        } else {
            F.height = F.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+30; //IE6, IE7 and Chrome
        }
    }

    window.onload=sizeFrame;
    //-->
</script>
```

Comment: I would try putting it in the `<head></head>` of the document. Also, make sure to change the "myFrame" to the id of your div.